# How to convert string to HTML codes in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a field in the database which store script tags and I want to implement those script tags into my HTML file but the problem is that data is coming string format

I am trying this

```
<div class="mb-auto">{{htmlentities($video->ifram)}}</div>
```

Desired output

```
<script id="154896_p_269505" width="1280" height="720" src=""  class="dacast-video"></script>
```

But getting

```
"&lt;script id=&quot;154896_p_269505&quot; width=&quot;1280&quot; height=&quot;720&quot; src=&quot;https://player.dacast.com/js/player.js?contentId=154896_p_269505&quot; class=&quot;dacast-video&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"
```

Comment: Not sure if there is automatic escaping done, but removing `htmlentities()` may be a start.

Comment: @NigelRen By removing htmlentities() the result is coming in a string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by replacing

```html
<div class="mb-auto">{{htmlentities($video->ifram)}}</div>
```

with

```html
<div class="mb-auto">{!! $video->ifram !!}</div>
```

But you should be very careful about XSS attack since the JavaScript present in your string will be interpreted by the browser. NEVER do it with a user-provided content!

Comment: Is there any safer way, so I can escape `XSS attack`

Comment: Since you allow arbitrary JavaScript to be interpreted, there is a XSS vulnerability. If you really need to do this, be sure the content cannot be updated except by yourself